# How to load a dll in Karaf container?

Tags: dll, karaf

I have a dll which provides a simple functionality (called HelloCpp.dll) and
I need to access to the content of this library from Karaf container via REST calls. 
I created a simple maven bundle which provides the REST api and a class (HelloJNI) which loads HelloCpp.dll using: `System.loadLibrary("HelloCpp");`

I have also addressed this dll in my POM file using: `<Bundle-NativeCode>HelloCpp.dll</Bundle-NativeCode>`

I have coppied the dll in both project directory and also karaf/lib folder.

I can successfuly install the bundle and I don't receive any compilation error as well, but when I deploy my bundle into Karaf container and try to start bundle, I get this error message: No matching native libraries found.

Could you please help me to solve the problem? Maybe I don't address the dll correctly in the POM file.

Thanks in advance,
Mandana